# Python: match one of multiple regex patterns and extract IP address if match

Tags: python, regex

I am using python to parse Postfix logfiles. I need to match lines containing any of multiple patterns, and extract IP address if line matches

```
ip = re.search('^warning: Connection rate limit exceeded: [0-9]* from .*\[([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\] for service smtp', message)
if not ip:
    ip = re.search('^NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from .*\[([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\]: .*: Relay access denied; .*', message)
    if not ip:
        ip = re.search('^NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from .*\[([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\]: .*:  Recipient address rejected: .*', message)
...
...
print ip.group(1)
```

Any line will only ever match one pattern. I know that normaly I can use '(pattern1|pattern2|pattern3)' to match any of multiple patterns, but since I am alredy using parenthesis `()` to group the IP address which I want to extract, I don't know how to do that.

I will have quite a lot of patterns to match. What would be the most clean/elegant way to do it ?

Comment: Please include your input, current output and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a *non-capturing group*:

```
patterns = [
    "warning: Connection rate limit exceeded: [0-9]* from .*\[([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\] for service smtp",
    "NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from .*\[([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\]: .*: Relay access denied; .*",
    "NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from .*\[([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})\]: .*:  Recipient address rejected: .*"
]
pattern = re.compile("^(?:" + "|".join(patterns) + ")")
ip = pattern.search(message)
```

Comment: what does `"^(?:"` in the `re.compile` expression mean ?

Comment: @MartinVegter `^` is the beginning of the string, `(?:)` is a non-capturing group itself.

Comment: it almost works, but when I do `if ip: print ip.group(1)`, then it prints `None`. Obviously, it matched my pattern (because `if ip` evaluated as true), but it does not print the matched ip.

Comment: I see what's happening: `ip.group(1)` is `None` when the second pattern matched. In which case the ip is in `ip.group(2)`. But I don't know which of my patterns matched. How can I print `ip.group(n)`, where `n` is the only non-`None` value ?

Comment: @MartinVegter got it, have you tried looking into `groups()`? Thanks.